# Does DeferredResult have a race condition when returning a potentially already-set instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, deferred

I'm using [DeferredResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) in my Spring MVC application to handle some server-side processing of a potentially long-running action. It might be *very* fast, or it could take a second or two.

But in either case, the incoming HTTP request causes an action to be pushed to a queue, which a *separate* thread (via an `ExecutorService`) is responsible for consuming. A callback is then called, notifying the pusher that the operation has completed.

I refactored some of this behavior into a utility method:

```
    public static DeferredResult<String> toResponse(GameManager gameManager, final Player player, Action action) {
        DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        gameManager.execute(action, new Handler<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Result result) {
                JSONObject obj;
                try {
                    obj = gameManager.getGameJSON(player);
                    obj.put("success", result.getResult());
                    obj.put("message", result.getMessage());
                    deferredResult.setResult(obj.toString());  // POINT B
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    deferredResult.setErrorResult(e);
                }
            }
        });
        return deferredResult; // POINT A
    }
```

But I'm wondering **what happens** if the execution of the action happens so quickly that the `setResult()` method is called (`POINT B`) on the `DeferredResult` *before* it has been returned (`POINT A`) to the calling method.

Will Spring see the returned `DeferredResult` already has a value and handle it, or does it only begin "watching" for the setter to be called *after* the instance has been provided?

Comment: Is GameMangager the executor service? What is Action?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Spring but would say that `Class DeferredResult<>` would be a pretty poor implementation of a Deferred if settlement timing made any difference to the downstream behaviour.

It seems safe to assume that the behaviour would be identical regardless of asynchronous process' timing - milliseconds, seconds or whatever, with the only proviso that a timeout didn't occur in which case the `onTimeout` handler would run (if set). Even if the Deferred was settled synchronously, in the same code block that created it, the caller function should act on the outcome as expected.

If this assumption is not valid then the `Class DeferredResult<>` is not fit for purpose and shouldn't be used.